# Following a python learning tutorial but my code isn't showing the correct output and I can't figure out why

Tags: python

I'm following a python tutorial and making a tic tac toe game, and after making a check for who won I noticed that whenever I check for diagonal_1, the winner variable is a dash when it should be an X, for all other cases the check works.

```
# ---- Global Variables ----

# Game Board
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]

# If game is still going
game_still_going = True

# Who won or tie
winner = None

# Whose turn is it
current_player = "X"


def display_board():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2])
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5])
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8])


def play_game():
    # Display initial board
    display_board()

    while game_still_going:

        handle_turn(current_player)

        check_if_game_over()

        flip_player()

    # The game has ended
    if winner == "X" or winner == "O":
        print(winner + " won")
    elif winner is None:
        print("Tie.")


def handle_turn(player):
    position = int(input("Choose a position from 1 to 9: ")) - 1

    board[position] = "X"
    display_board()


def check_if_game_over():
    check_for_winner()
    check_if_tie()


def check_for_winner():
    # Set up global variable
    global winner

    row_winner = check_rows()

    column_winner = check_columns()

    diagonal_winner = check_diagonals()
    if row_winner:
        winner = row_winner
    elif column_winner:
        winner = column_winner
    elif diagonal_winner:
        winner = diagonal_winner
    else:
        winner = None
    return


def check_rows():
    global game_still_going

    row_1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "-"
    row_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != "-"
    row_3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != "-"
    if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
        game_still_going = False
    if row_1:
        return board[0]
    elif row_2:
        return board[3]
    else:
        return board[6]


def check_columns():
    global game_still_going

    column_1 = board[0] == board[3] == board[6] != "-"
    column_2 = board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != "-"
    column_3 = board[2] == board[5] == board[8] != "-"
    if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
        game_still_going = False
    if column_1:
        return board[0]
    elif column_2:
        return board[1]
    else:
        return board[2]


def check_diagonals():
    global game_still_going

    diagonal_1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != "-"
    diagonal_2 = board[2] == board[4] == board[6] != "-"
    if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
        game_still_going = False
    if diagonal_2:
        return board[2]
    elif diagonal_1:
        return board[0]


def check_if_tie():
    return


def flip_player():
    return


play_game()
```

This is all the code for the game. I have been trying to figure out why it's not working as intended but I can't figure it out.

Also this is my first time using Stack Overflow so sorry if my formatting isn't good, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

When you're checking the rows and columns, the functions always return a value even if there is no winner. They should return nothing if no winner.

Here is the updated code:

```
def check_rows():
    global game_still_going

    row_1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "-"
    row_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != "-"
    row_3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != "-"
    if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
        game_still_going = False
    if row_1:
        return board[0]
    elif row_2:
        return board[3]
    elif row_3:
        return board[6]
    # return nothing


def check_columns():
    global game_still_going

    column_1 = board[0] == board[3] == board[6] != "-"
    column_2 = board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != "-"
    column_3 = board[2] == board[5] == board[8] != "-"
    if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
        game_still_going = False
    if column_1:
        return board[0]
    elif column_2:
        return board[1]
    elif column_3:
        return board[2]
    # return nothing


def check_diagonals():
    global game_still_going

    diagonal_1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != "-"
    diagonal_2 = board[2] == board[4] == board[6] != "-"
    if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
        game_still_going = False
        return board[4]  # diagonal always crosses center
    # return nothing
```